# Data validation formula error

Tags: excel, validation

I have a formula that returns the right result when used in a cell

```
=AND(LI_Locaux_No,VLOOKUP(C7,TableGestionLocaux,16,FALSE)=C6)
```

which return True

When I put the same formula in Data Validation it does tell me that there is an error but I know that it's not because of that that it doesn't work.

Basically I am checking if the value in C7 exist in a named range and check if C6 is in another named range where C6 is the offset of C7

Any idea?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can not use a `Table` in formula when you use it in data validation. Excel do not allow it. You can use `Named` range rather than `Table`.

Comment: Both are named range even if the name say table

Comment: Table is specially formatted as table in excel but named range is not a table. So, put your data in sheet then manually assign name of those range having data. Then use that named range as array of `Vlookup()` formula.

Comment: What is `LI_Locaux_No`? If it is a named range which is outcome of it in `AND` formula?

Comment: When used in a cell and not in data validation, the same exact formula does return True; LI_Locaux_no is ='Gestion des locaux'!$B$11:$B$14841 and TableGestionLocaux is ='Gestion des locaux'!$B$11:$Q$14841

Comment: Again, I assume you are using a table not named range. Tables are also named range but named ranges are not table. Can you share a sample file via dropbox or google drive and put link here.

Comment: If it was a table I would have the table tab appears when clicking in one of the cell of the table design too,  which it doesn't. I have 2 files using the same validation, it works in one but not the other. Could it be the number of cells in the named range? it contains about 237k cells in the file where it doesn't work. I will try to put a demo file together using my data,  not so simple with all the VBA (50k line) and data behind it

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out,

Was much simpler then I tought,  since in my named range I have both strings and number, everything was formated as text, same for the lookup cell. Forgot that Vlookup doesn't like numbers formated as string. Changed cell to general in both and works fine with formula